# How can I add a pre-defined option in GooglePlacesAutocomplete?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to add a pre-defined option for "Your Location" as one of the search results using GooglePlacesAutocomplete by react-google-places-autocomplete.

```
 <AutocompleteInput
          apiKey="AIzaSyAh3GK6nfhMrlMhGxtyBwRGIsYbiqoTYQA" // Replace with your own Google Maps API key
          selectProps={{
            // defaultInputValue: "Current Location",
            isClearable: true,
            value: address,
            onChange: (val) => {
              setAddress(val);
            },
            // options: [
            //   ...(address ? [] : [{ label: "Current Location", value: "currentLocation" }]), // Add "Current Location" option to options array
            // ],
            placeholder: "Enter location",
            filterOption: (option, inputValue) => {
              // Filter options based on input value
              console.log("Potential options:", option);
              if (inputValue) {
                return option.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase());
              }
              return true;
            },
            styles: {
              control: (provided, state) => ({
                ...provided,
                borderColor: "grey", // Set border color to transparent to remove border
                boxShadow: "none", // Remove box shadow
                cursor: "text", // Set cursor to text to remove pointer cursor
                "&:select": {
                  borderColor: "#4B9CE6", // Set border color to transparent on hover
                },
              }),
              indicatorSeparator: () => ({
                display: "none", // Hide the indicator separator
              }),
              dropdownIndicator: () => ({
                display: "none", // Hide the dropdown indicator
              }),
              option: (provided, state) => ({
                ...provided,
                color: state.isFocused ? "#4B9CE6" : "black", // set color of option
                backgroundColor: "white", // set background color of option
                "& em": {
                  color: "#4B9CE6", // set color for matching letters
                  fontWeight: "normal", // set font weight for matching letters
                  textDecoration: "underline", // add underline to matching letters
                },
              }),
              input: (provided) => ({
                ...provided,
                width: "50%",
                height: "40px",
                lineHeight: "35px",
                marginLeft: "35px",
              }),
              placeholder: (provided) => ({
                ...provided,
                marginLeft: "35px",
              }),
              singleValue: (provided) => ({
                ...provided,
                marginLeft: "35px",
              }),
            },
          }}
        />
```

I'm trying to add an option so that users can click "your location" to search their location as one of the search suggestions.